# CKEditor, dialogue iframe UI element change the SRC

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm building a custom CKEditor plugin, and I have in the dialog an IFrame UI Element (I did use the iframedialog plugin for this).

On the setup function of this iFrame I have a code that in some cases need to change the SRC of the iFrame, couldn't succeed in doing this.

Can anyone help me please, below I attached a snippet of what I want to do

```
{
    type: 'iframe',
    id: 'internalLinkFrame',
    src: 'http://test.mytree.com/',
    setup: function( data ) {
        if ( data.internalLink ) {
            console.log("Loading the ID from this URL ");
            // Tried this but didn't work
            this.setValue(data.internalLink);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621681/change-ckeditor-iframe-dialog-url/30424277#30424277